# Python Request Library multiple API calls sequentially in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, python-requests

In our project we are reading historical data(past 45 days data) from solr db.We can read maximum 5 days data in single api call so we are calling api sequentially in a for loop for 45 days.But observing some 400 status codes for some api call' in between randomly..like for total 9 api calls some giving 200 and some 400 response codes in between randomly..like if I rerun my job, then api call which gave 400 earlier might give 200 this time.
I checked with API owner, they said it is because you are calling next api call before earlier one is completed.

1.) how to identify if api request is completed in python , so that can call next api only when previous request is completed.This can be answered by API owner or there is any way in python request library

2.) should i think of using sleep statement after each api call.But how to know sleep time and is this efficient way ?

Thanks

Comment: please show your efforts with what you have tried.. and what issue you faced

Comment: 1. the api itself need improve 2. requests.get/post by default is blocking, and please paste your demo code of loops so we might investigate.

Comment: It would be useful to see how you are calling these api calls as of now.

Comment: if you run all requests in one thread then new request runs when previous request is completed.

Comment: maybe you should use [requests-cache](https://github.com/reclosedev/requests-cache) to keep correct responses on local computer - and next time it would get data from cache.

Comment: some API may restrict how often you can send request - ie. only 2 requests in 1 second - and this can make problem if you run too many requests in short time. But this you should check in documentation. Maybe documentation also explain when it can send response 400.